# Using jQuery with HttpHandlers

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, httphandler

I am trying to return HTML from a HttpHandler via jQuery. I am using the following jQuery javascript to call the handler:

```
$.get('http://localhost:56964/LoadComments.axd?storyID=' + storyID ,function(data) {
alert(data);
});
```

The handler performs some processing and returns HTML. The problem I am having is that the above call results in a 404 with no response. If I call the same URL as above in the browser, the HTML is returned back to the browser, no problem.

I am setting the following Response headers in the handler:

```
 context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
 context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
 context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
 context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.MinValue);
 context.Response.StatusCode = 200;

 context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

If it matters, part of the returned HTML contains a script block, wrapped in script tags. I am guessing it does not matter since it works fine when calling directly from the browser.

I cannot figure out what is going wrong. Please help :P

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just using a relative URL?  As in:

```
$.get('LoadComments.axd?storyID=' + storyID
```

Comment: Hi Josh -- Yes, I do, and am able to verify that it is working by calling the URL directly from the browser.

Comment: Well, WTF. That works. Is there some limitation with the jquery call that does not allow the use of absolute URLs? Glad to get this answered, it was driving me insane. Thanks :)

Comment: I do not believe the issue is with using an absolute URI, but with going over an abnormal port such as 56964.